# Github api CREATEPULLREQUEST (Java api )

Tags: java, github-api

org.eclipse.egit.github.core.client.RequestException: Invalid request. "base", "head" weren't supplied. (422)

Source code

```
pullRequestService = new PullRequestService(gitHubClient);
PullRequest request=new PullRequest();                                 
request.setTitle("a fix");                                              
request.setBody("this is a fix");                                       
request.setHead(new PullRequestMarker().setRef("testBranch"));          
request.setBase(new PullRequestMarker().setRef("master"));              
pullRequestService.createPullRequest(repo,request);
```

testBranch Branch is created in my repo.
not able to create pull request through java api

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert of github api, but by checking the code, I suspect you should call `setLabel()` instead of `setRef()`, as the PullRequestService works with the label value as base and head:

```
String base = baseMarker.getLabel();
if (base != null)
    params.put(PR_BASE, base);
```

[Repo](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/55b54c291576e4d6f2bdc27306192ba5ae438655/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/PullRequestService.java#L214)

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered same error when tried creating pull request using `egit.github.core` api. Finally below code worked for me.

```
PullRequestService pullRequestService = new PullRequestService(client);
pullRequestService.getClient().setCredentials("<userid>", "<password>");
RepositoryId repo = RepositoryId.createFromId("<owenerName>" + "/" + "repoName");

PullRequest request = new PullRequest();
request.setTitle("Please merge");
request.setBody("Please merge");
request.setHead(new PullRequestMarker().setRef("<branchName>").setLabel("< branchName >"));
request.setBase(new PullRequestMarker().setRef("master").setLabel("master"));

pullRequestService.createPullRequest(repo,request);
```

Just make sure branch exists and has commit pushed to it.